# Mapbox React Native, ShapeSource#images is deprecated, please use Images#images

Tags: react-native, mapbox

I'm using the last version of MapBox React Native on my project, and everything is working great except I'm getting a warning, 
***ShapeSource#images is deprecated, please use Images#images***
how can I fix that?

thanks for your help

**Edit: my implementation after riastard answer, I hope it helps someone.**

```
    <>
            <MapboxGL.Images
              images={{someIcon: someIcon, someIcon2: someIcon2, someIcon3: someIcon3}}
            />
            <MapboxGL.ShapeSource
            id="symbolLocationSource"
            hitbox={{ width: 20, height: 20 }}
            onPress={this.onSourceLayerPress}
            shape={featureCollection}
            >

            <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
              id="symbolLocationSymbols"
              minZoomLevel={1}
              style={{
                iconImage: '{icon}',
                iconSize: 0.25,
                iconAllowOverlap: true
              }}
            />

          </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
    </>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the descriptive error you're seeing, it sounds like you can avoid this warning by using the [`Images`](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/Images.md) object to indicate what client side bitmap/drawable to use as the icon for your symbol layer rather than the older API. Doing this now will probably save you some frustration in the future when `ShapeSource#images` is fully deprecated.

Comment: I searched the whole documentation but I didn't find anything, but it's clear I didn't search good enough. Thanks Man